# How do I use a custom Json Serializer inside another serializer

Tags: java, json, serialization

I have some Objects

```
public class MyObject {
    private String name;
    private String city;
    public MyObject(String n, String c) {
       name=n; city=c;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public String getCity() {return city;}
    public void setName(String n) {name=n;}
    public void setCity(String c) {city =c;}
}
```

And i have a custom serializer:

```
public class MySerializer implements JsonSerializer<MyObject> {
public JsonElement serialize(final MyObject myobj, final Type type,      JsonSerializationContext context) {
    JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
    result.add("id", new JsonPrimitive(myobj.getName()));
    return result;
}
}
```

Basically i just want to serilize only 1 of the 2 fields.  this works great when do something like:

```
       GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
       builder.registerTypeAdapter(MyObject.class, new MySerialize());
       Gson gson = builder.create();
       System.out.println(gson.toJson(new MyObject("test","something"));
```

however it gets a bit more complicated (and here is my question) when i have another object which is made up of "MyObject"s.  How can i get the correct serializer to only serialize the one field of MyObject.

so i have another class:

```
public class SomeObject {
   private String id;
   private MyObject foo;
   private MyObject bar;
   ...
}
```

and i have a custom serializer:

```
  public JsonElement serialize(final SomeObject something, final Type type,            JsonSerializationContext context) {
    JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
            result.add("id", new JsonPrimitive(something.getId()));

            //here i need help
            result.add("myobject1", new JsonPrimitive(gson.toJson(something.getFoo())));

           return result;
        }
```

I'm not sure if its best practice to create the GsonBuilder for "MyObject" inside the custom serializer for SomeObject is it?

ive tried something like:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(MyObject.class, new MySerialize());
builder.registerTypeAdapter(SomeObject.class, new SomeObjectSerializer());
Gson gson = builder.create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(new SomeObject("id",new MyObject("test","something"),new                   MyObject("test2,"barrrrr"));
```

and i would exepct "{"id":"id","foo"{"id":"test"},"bar":{"id:"test2"}}

but that is not the case.  bascially i want just the first field in a custom object whcih i have a seralizer for, but do i need to build that serializer inside another objects custom serializer?  seems wrong, dunno why.

Answer (score 2):

Note how you have access to the `JsonSerializationContext` in your custom `JsonSerializer` classes. You can call [`JsonSerializationContext#serialize(Object)`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializationContext.html#serialize%28java.lang.Object%29) and Gson will use a registered or default [`TypeAdapter`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) to serialize that object and return a [`JsonElement`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html) which you can add to the outer `JsonElement`.

Comment: Just tried that and get the same result.  How do i know if the SomeObjectSerializer() has been defined in the context.  For example, im adding it to the GsonBuilder() before called "create" which is used to get the toJson string, but it doesnt seem to be called.

Comment: @user Try debugging and checking if the `SomeObjectSerializer` is actually registered when you call `JsonSerializationContext#serialize()`.